# IEnumerator for HashTable?

Tags: c#, linq

Can anyone tell me why is a IDictionaryEnumerator preferred for looping a HashTable.

How is it different from IEnumerator although it is derived from it?

When to use which?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IDictionaryEnumerator allows you to access both the key and the value of the current entry.  As you note, an IDictionaryEnumerator is an IEnumerator, so if you're just using it in a foreach, you'll only notice this because the range variable is a DictionaryEntry; but if you're working with the IDictionaryEnumerator manually, you'll find it has Key and Value properties as well as Current.

It's not so much that it is 'preferred' for looping a Hashtable -- it's just that if you enumerate a Hashtable, you're enumerating key-value pairs, not just values, and the IDictionaryEnumerator represents that.

Answer (score 7):

The point is that a hashtable/dictionary enumerates *pairs*, with a `.Key` and `.Value`. This is a bit moot from 2.0, since `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` which is clearer.

This interface simply makes it more convenient to access the key/value in a few cases.

You can achieve the same in `Hashtable` (without using `IDictionaryEnumerator`) via:

```
foreach(DictionaryEntry pair in hashTable) {
     .... use pair.Key and pair.Value
}
```

Comment: This interface simply makes it more convenient to access the key/value in a few cases -- which cases? Can you cite examples?

Answer (score 0):

IDictionaryEnumerator is specially designed for enumerating over collections of key/value pairs. It gives you access to the key and value of the current entry (among other things, as seen in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.idictionaryenumerator.aspx)). IEnumerator would only give you the current value.